# Restricting and redirecting other user from admin in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm getting issue after logging in the site. There are two kinds of users i.e. 'admin','employer'. When I've logged in by employer, I can access the restricted area of Admin. Below is the AppController of the site..

```
class AppController extends Controller {
        public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time', 'Auth');

        // Change template extension to .php instead of .ctp
        var $ext = '.php';
        public $components = array(
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array(
                'loginAction' => array(
                    'controller' => 'users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email'))),
                'authorize' => array('Controller')
            )
        );

        public function isAuthorized($user) {

            // Admin can access every action
            if (isset($user['type']) && $user['type'] === 'admin') {
                return true;
            }

            // Default deny
            return false;
        }

        public function beforeFilter() {
            $this->Auth->allow(array('view', 'index','assessment','question'));
        } 
    }
```

Now here is the controller which has methods for admin.

```
class TopicsController extends AppController {

    public $scaffold = 'admin';
    public function beforeFilter() {

        if($this->Auth->user('type')!='employer'){
           parent::beforeFilter();
           $this->Auth->allow(array('view', 'index','moveup'));
        } else {
           $this->Auth->deny(array('view', 'index','moveup'));
           $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'employer' , 'action' => 'index'));
        }

    }
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function index() {
      $this->set('topics', $this->Topic->children());
    }

}
```

If admin URL is **www.example.com/admin/topics** , Employer is redirected to **www.example.com/admin/employer** which is not right URL to be redirected.

Also want to know about `public $scaffold = 'admin';` as It's little unclear to me.
Please help me..

Comment: about the `$scaffold = 'admin'`; read: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/scaffolding.html. Have you tried: `$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'employer' , 'action' => 'index', 'admin'=>false));`

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'd gone through the link. I never tried before, and hopefully it's working nice.. thank you very much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.. Found one way to redirect, which made my issue solved for a now.. Still looking for proper answer if anybody has..

I changed code from

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'employer' , 'action' => 'index'));
```

to

```
$this->redirect('employer');
```

..
**EDIT:** Thanks Alex, I've used

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'employer' , 'action' => 'index', 'admin'=>false));
```

and it's working too..

Comment: If you want to redirect this is the way. You can also pass the HTTP Status Code as the second parameter to this function - so all 3xx codes apply.